# Birnbaum-Saunders distribution, question about notation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A stochastic variable X is said to follow the two-parameter Birnbaum-Saunders distribution, we write $X \in BS(\alpha,\beta) $ if its distribution function is

$$ F_X(x) = \begin{cases} \phi(\frac{1}{\alpha}(\sqrt{\frac{x}{\beta}}-\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{x}}) \qquad x > 0\\ 0 \qquad \text{else}  \end{cases}$$

where $ \phi $ is the cumulative distribution function of $N(0,1)$.

Im a little confused with a distribution inside another distribution, is this correct?

Let $\gamma = \frac{1}{\alpha}(\sqrt{\frac{x}{\beta}}-\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{x}}). $

$$ F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x (\int_{-\infty}^{\gamma}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-z^2/2}dz)d\gamma $$

for x > 0.

What's confusing me is that $ \gamma = \gamma(x).$

Comment: Your second formula for $F_X(x)$ is not correct. It should be only the inner $dz$-integral. With your notation you could write $F_X(x)=\phi(\gamma(x))$. Nothing is confusing about that.

Comment: Yea. I messed up the distribution and probability dense function, thanks!

Comment: It is an older and more useful convention to use $\Phi(x)$ for the CDF of an $N(0,1)$ distribution and $\phi(x)$ for the density.  (Machine learning tried to reinvent things but managed to make them more confusing.)  So you want $F_X(x)=\Phi(\gamma(x))=\int_{-\infty}^{\gamma(x)} \phi(z)\, dz = \int_{-\infty}^{\gamma(x)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-z^2/2}\,dz$.